# Is it possible to use Sharepoint Client Object Model for a Windows Application?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

Is it possible to use Sharepoint Client Object Model for a Windows Application?
If yes then how to do it?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Based on your comments it looks like you are trying to use types from the Server Object Model, not the Client Object Model. Check the types you are using - if the type name is prefixed with SP or the type is in the Microsoft.SharePoint namespace it's from the Server Object Model

Comment: I wrote a course for Pluralsight on how to use the Client Object Model. You can get a free trial subscription and check it out:  http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sp2010-client-object-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; and you do it the same way you would create any other Windows application, including the relevant references and writing the code.

Comment: I've already tried that.But it didn't work.Getting the following error :- "The type or namespace name 'Sharepoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'" though I've added references to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client and Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime

Comment: @DeathRider are you using .NET 3.5 in 64bit mode? If you post code, we may be able to help more, but it does sound like a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by TZHX you can, please refer to these for help:

msdn wiki

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620623

this is an example using the client side object model example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Introduction

and another example

http://weblogs.asp.net/shailesh/archive/2010/07/07/sharepoint-2010-introduction-to-client-object-model.aspx

the paths to dll's are:

> Path to get DLL's: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web
>   Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'm able to fix the problem.I missed out one very small but crucial thing.My Target Framework was set to '.NET Framework 4' which should be '.NET Framework 3.5'.Changed it accordingly and it has started working.